# Is there any benefit of using generic reference type parameter, if class's interface is contravariant?

Tags: c#, generics

Consider this class:

```
class MyClass<T> where T: class // or T: BaseClass
{
    void DoSomething1(T arg){ ... }
    void DoSomething2(T arg){ ... }
    ...
    void DoSomethingN(T arg){ ... }
}
```

And there is no return of `T` values! Even in protected property or field, so descendants cannot return `T` as well.

Is there any advantage of using generic parameter here comparing to just hardcoded base class type?

Comment: I don't see the problem/question here. Why do you want to have the functions to return `T`? `T` is used as parameter. In your example the constraint refers to the 'referencial' ability of `T`. If you would have choosen `T : BaseClass` then there might be no usecase to use a generic paramter.

Comment: I would say no, because I dont see any posibility to use the concrete type - if it can not be used, there is no value in defining it.

Comment: @JNS May be there is some space for optimization. In case when T is a sealed class can compiler emit a call without the need look into VMT?

Comment: @voroninp: Thats right... However, I couldn't imagine any use case where such kind of performance improvment would be discernible.

Comment: @JNS That's is why I am asking. Btw, if generic constraints supported structural typing, then it would be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no advantage. Since you only pass parameters of type `T` your methods are essentially [contravariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx), so you might as well declare them to take a `BaseClass` reference rather than a `T`.